# Check if two column values found in other pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**Set-up**

I have 2 pandas dfs (df1 and df2) which contain some overlapping rows and some non-overlapping rows.

Both dfs have the columns `order_id` and `shop`.

Now, if a df1 row matches with a df2 row on the combination of `order_id` and `shop`, then nothing. But if a df1 row doesn't match with a df2 row on the combination of `order_id` and `shop`, then this df1 row should be added to df2.

---

**Example**

`df2` is such that,

```
    order_id    shop
0     12345     'NL'
1     45678     'FR'
2     12345     'DE'
3     34567     'NL'
```

Now if `df1` such that,

```
    order_id    shop
0     12345     'NL'
1     45678     'FR'
```

then nothing.

---

But if `df1` such that,

```
        order_id    shop
0       12345       'NL'
1       99999       'FR'
2       12345       'UK'
```

then row 1 and 2 should be added to `df2` even though `shop` value for row 1 and `order_id` for row 2 are already in `df2`.

The resulting `df2` should look like,

```
    order_id    shop
0     99999     'FR'
1     12345     'UK'        
2     12345     'NL'
3     45678     'FR'
4     12345     'DE'
5     34567     'NL'
```

Note that the `order_id` column is int and the `shop` column is string.

So in graphical terms what I want to achieve looks like:

### [image]

**Code**

I created a monstrous line which then didn't really work...

So far, I have,

```
result_df = df1[(~df1['order_id'].astype(str).isin(df2['order_id'].astype(str)))]
```

How do I solve this?

---

**EXTRA**

if `df1` such that,

```
        order_id    shop
0       12345       'NL'
1       99999       'FR'
2       12345       'UK'
```

how do I compare `df1` with `df2` such that I get `df3` which looks like,

```
        order_id    shop
0       99999       'FR'
1       12345       'UK'
```

Comment: Are all rows unique?

Comment: Ha, that's something I should consider more often! Yes, they are.

Comment: Good news, so first solution working nice for you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all rows are unique use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df = pd.concat([df2, df1], ignore_index=True).drop_duplicates()
print (df)
   order_id  shop
0     12345  'NL'
1     45678  'FR'
2     12345  'DE'
3     34567  'NL'
5     99999  'FR'
6     12345  'UK'
```

If not unique filter not equal rows by [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with `indicator=True` and then `concat` to `df2`:

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2, how='left', indicator=True).query('_merge == "left_only"')[df1.columns]
df = pd.concat([df2, df3], ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Thanks! Though I'm getting a `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'` on the 'unique-case' concat command.

Comment: @LucSpan - So `print (pd.concat([df2, df1]))` not working?

Comment: hmm, so test `print (pd.concat([df2, df1], ignore_index=True))` and then `print (pd.concat([df2, df1], ignore_index=True).drop_duplicates())`

Comment: Yep, the issue is in adding the `.drop_duplicates()`. Adding `ignore_index` works.

Comment: I found the solution: `df = pd.concat([df2.astype(str), df1.astype(str)], ignore_index=True).drop_duplicates()`

Comment: I've added a related, additional question under **EXTRA**, do you know how to do that?

Comment: @LucSpan - Then test second solution, need `df3 = df1.merge(df2, how='left', indicator=True).query('_merge == "left_only"')[df1.columns]`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you wish to create a set of all the possible combinations? If so, you can create the unique pairs using the following:

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = {'order_id': [12345, 45678, 78901, 12345, 12901, 12345], 'shop': ['NL', 'FR', 'AB', 'AB', 'NL', 'NL']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=data1)

data2= {'order_id': [12345, 45678, 12345, 34567], 'shop': ['NL', 'FR', 'DE', 'NL']}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=data2)

df3 = df1
df3['Combi'] = df3['order_id'].astype('str') + df3['shop']
df3.drop_duplicates('Combi', inplace=True)
```

[image: df1]
[image: df3]

Comment: Thanks, but I don't wish to create a set of all possible combinations.

Comment: it's not exactly all possible combinations. it is the set of combinations that is in your dataset. Added the end results into the answer post